# .htaccess RewriteCond

Tags: web-services, apache, .htaccess

Can anyone halp me with this .htaccess file, i've been trying to make an exception so i can access my subdomain which is 
form.domain.com 
i tried with 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/form/?$
and several other commands but with no luck

.htaccess :

```
#######################
#   N - T H I N G !   #
#######################

# Apache options
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Allow only GET and POST verbs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST)$ [NC,OR]

# Ban Typical Vulnerability Scanners and others
# Kick out Script Kiddies
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(java|curl|wget).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(libwww-perl|curl|wget|python|nikto|wkito|pikto|scan|acunetix).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner).* [NC,OR]

# Error Page
ErrorDocument 404 /404

# Redirect attachments
RewriteRule ^files/attachments/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ files/attachments/$1/$2/$3 [L]

# Redirect all requests to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

To match a domain you should use %{HTTP_HOST} as in:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^form.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

That says if the domain matches form.domain.com, allow the URL and stop processing rules.

See the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for more details.